# 'ScrollTop' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dotnetnuke, captcha, recaptcha

I'm adding a recaptcha to a form on A DNN website. I wanted to use the asp.net Recaptcha control but it didn't seem to allow me to resize it easily.

I've decided to go for inserting the HTML into my page as in the example here:

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization

I works perfect on Chrome and Firefox..but not IE ..well at least not IE8 the version I'm using and I'm getting a javascript error 'ScrollTop' is null or not an object.  The error is occurring in dnncore.js

The only reference to ScrollTop are in the following js functions

```
function __dnn_bodyscroll() { 
var a = document.forms[0]; 
if (__dnn_ClientAPIEnabled() && __dnn_m_bPageLoaded) { 

//prob seems to happen on next lineafter a.
    a.ScrollTop.value = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : dnn.dom.getByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop 
}
```

}

```
function __dnn_setScrollTop(c) { 
if (__dnn_ClientAPIEnabled()) { 
    if (c == null) { 
        c = document.forms[0].ScrollTop.value 
    } 
    var a = dnn.getVar("ScrollToControl");
    if (a != null && a.length > 0) {
        var b = dnn.dom.getById(a);
        if (b != null) {
            c = dnn.dom.positioning.elementTop(b);
            dnn.setVar("ScrollToControl", "") 
        } 
    } 
    window.scrollTo(0, c) 
}
```

}

Is there an alternative to using this  ScrollTop in IE?

The HTML for the Recpatcha is

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var RecaptchaOptions = {
                tabindex: 1,
                theme: 'custom',
                custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha_widget'
            };

            function switchType(type) {
                var input = document.getElementById('recaptcha_response_field');
                if (type == 'audio') {
                    input.placeholder = "Type what you hear";
                    Recaptcha.switch_type('audio');
                } else {
                    input.placeholder = "Type the text";
                    Recaptcha.switch_type('image');
                }
            }
        </script>
        <div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display: none">
            <div id="recaptcha_image">
            </div>
            <div class="recaptcha_input left">
                <div class="recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol" style="color: red;">
                    Incorrect, please try again</div>
                <input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field"
                    placeholder="Type the text" />
            </div>
            <div class="recaptcha_buttons left">
                <a href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()" title="Get a new challenge" id="recaptcha_reload_btn">
                    <img src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/clean/refresh.png" id="recaptcha_reload"
                        alt="Get a new challenge" height="18" width="25"></a> <a href="javascript:switchType('audio');"
                            title="Get an audio challenge" id="recaptcha_switch_audio_btn" class="recaptcha_only_if_image">
                            <img src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/clean/audio.png" id="recaptcha_switch_audio"
                                alt="Get an audio challenge" height="15" width="25"></a> <a href="javascript:switchType('visual')"
                                    title="Get a visual challenge" id="recaptcha_switch_img_btn" class="recaptcha_only_if_audio">
                                    <img src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/clean/text.png" id="recaptcha_switch_img"
                                        alt="Get a visual challenge" height="15" width="25"></a>
                <a href="javascript:Recaptcha.showhelp()" title="Help" id="recaptcha_whatsthis_btn">
                    <img alt="Help" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/clean/help.png" id="recaptcha_whatsthis"
                        height="16" width="25"></a>
            </div>
            <img src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/clean/logo.png" id="recaptcha_logo"
                alt="" height="36" width="71">
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=mycaptchakey">
        </script>
        <noscript>
            <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=mycaptchakey"
                height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            <br>
            <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40" id="recaptcha_challenge_field" />
            <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" />
        </noscript>
```

There are no two  tags in the source of the page. I've seen some reasons for the cause of this was because of that.

Anyone came across this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think i found the cause of this which was to do with the textarea tag.

I replaced the ending of the "textarea" tag with "/textarea"

and it appears to have worked. #crazybug